# AngularJS - testing with Jasmine and mixpanel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mixpanel, karma-jasmine

Inside my angularJS application I use MixPanel to get analytics using the asynchronous script inside my index.html

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(e,b){if(!b.__SV){var a,f,i,g;window.mixpanel=b;a=e.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src=("https:"===e.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+'//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js';f=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];f.parentNode.insertBefore(a,f);b._i=[];b.init=function(a,e,d){function f(b,h){var a=h.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],h=a[1]);b[h]=function(){b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}}var c=b;"undefined"!== typeof d?c=b[d]=[]:d="mixpanel";c.people=c.people||[];c.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==d&&(a+="."+d);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};c.people.toString=function(){return c.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};i="disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");for(g=0;g<i.length;g++)f(c,i[g]);
  b._i.push([a,e,d])};b.__SV=1.2}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
  mixpanel.init("@@mixPanelId");
</script>
```

I'm writing test using Karma and Jasmine.
When I'm running **karma:unit**, I have the following error : **ReferenceError: mixpanel is not defined**

This is due to the call I make to MixPanel inside one of my service :

```
mixpanel.register_once({
  BrowserVersion: "#{browserInfos.browser}-#{browserInfos.version}"
})
```

Do you have any idea how can I include MixPanel to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simulate mixpanel I created a simple mock :

**test/mock/mixpanel.coffee**

```
class MixpanelMock
  track: () ->
    console.log("mixpanel.track", arguments)
  register_once: () ->
    console.log("mixpanel.register_once", arguments)

window.mixpanel = new MixpanelMock()
```

Then I just added it in **karma.conf.js** and everything worked fine.

Comment: More informations about it inside this [blog post](http://blog.james-lafa.fr/angularjs-how-to-mock-mixpanel-inside-for-your-tests/)